# zabbix trigger for difference between 2 values from 2 fields

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I am trying to figure out how to have Zabbix pull values from 2 fields, compare them and trigger if  the  difference between them exceeds a certain value

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

If one is always larger than the other and using a threshold of 13:

```
{host:item1.last()}-{host:item2.last()}>13
```

If their relative sizes are unknown, cannot think of anything nicer but this:

```
({host:item1.last()}-{host:item2.last()}>13) or ({host:item2.last()}-{host:item1.last()}>13)
```

Comment: Would be great for the author of the downvote to provide their reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the two fields as standard items (snmp values, agent values etc), then create a [calculated item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) with their difference and appy to it your triggers.